# Angular directive is not adding css class to another element

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

Hi i am trying an angular directive changes the CSS of another element when a button is clicked,however despite the console.log shows me that the class was added, in the inspector still without the class.

ModalDirective

```
angular.module('App.shared.modal')
.directive('openModal', function (Config) {

  function link(scope, element, attrs) {
    element.bind('click', function() {
      var modal = angular.element(document.querySelector('#' + attrs.openModal)).css('display', 'block');
      setTimeout(function(){ modal.className += ' modal-in'}, 10);
    });
  }
  return {
    restrict: 'AEC',
    link: link
  };
});
```

View which is called the directive

```
<header class="">
  <div class="u-max-full-width">
    <div class="row homehubusa-header">
      <div class="one-third column">
        <img src="./imgs/homehubusa.png" alt="logo homehubusa" class="logo"/>
      </div>
      <div class="two-thirds column">
        <ul class="menu u-pull-right">
          <li>
            <a href="#">HomesUSA</a><span class="separator">&nbsp;</span>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Support</a><span class="separator">&nbsp;</span>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
          </li>
          <li class="callsign">
            <a href="#" class="button button-danger" open-modal="modalLogin">Sign in</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Header Directive

```
  angular.module('App.shared.header')
    .directive('appHeader', function (Config) {

      function link(scope) {
        scope.navLinks = [
          {title: 'Home', href: 'home'},
          {title: 'Help', href: 'seed-help'}
        ];
      }
      return {
        templateUrl: Config.rootPath + 'shared/header/header-view.html',
        link: link,
        replace: true
      };
    });
```

The app structure

```
<body ng-app="App">  
  <app-header></app-header> /* This is the header directive, here is the button */
  <div class="ng-view"></div> /* Here is the modal */
  <app-footer></app-footer>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to use `timeout` to make the CSS applied. Check a simplified example here: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0c36m3w5/1).

You'd better use `addClass` as it is supported by [`angular.element`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element):

```
 link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    element.bind('click', function() {
      var target = angular.element(document.querySelector('#test'));
      target.css('display', 'block');
      target.addClass('red');
    });
```

For the `display: block`, I am doubting that your element `#modalLogin` is not there, because from my example, it is working: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0c36m3w5/2/).

Comment: but the css display block should be work also, but not work

Answer (score 0):

You can check the $apply() method. because you are using setTimeout() method. setTimeout() is asynchronous which is handled by the JS Engine. not Angular Compiler so somehow you need the way to tell the Angular that i Js engine have change something hence try to use apply(). I don't know this will work. one of my code i have done this thing. it worked.